# How to downscale from 4k to 1080P

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have a video in 4k that i would like to downscale to 1080p. What i want to do is having the video with the same quality and carachteristics as the original but at 1080p.

I have tried the following:

1.- changing the output resolution to 1080p.
2.- stablished the "Percentage scale for render resolution" to 100%.
3.- Output: FFmepg
4.- Encoding:
       - output quality: Losless

the problem is that I ended up with a file with a size of 8 GB when the original video file 2GB.

Any help, please?

Comment: Which quality is it you are talking about? The quality I am thinking of cannot be preserved when changing from 4k to 1080.

Comment: I guess your input video isn't encoded as lossless, otherwise it would be much bigger as well, it must already be encoded with compression. Try using a compression if you wnt a smaller file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a compression like H264. Your 4k Video has also a compression on it and that the reason why it is smaller than your 1080 video.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to downscale the video (so no cuts or anything like that), I don't think that blender is your best choice here.

I usually use handbrake (https://handbrake.fr/) for that purpose.

---

If you want to use blender anyway you could try several things:

1. Use "perceptually lossless". Maybe the file is small enough for your purpose
2. Set the encoding speed to "Very slow, smalest file". As far as I know in this mode the decoder tries longer to figure out the best way to get the same quality but with a smaller file size. As the text says, it takes longer for that though.
3. You can also try "None, use constant bitrate". Under "Rate" below on the left you can set the minimum, maximum and average bitrate. Here you can experiment with different values and see if the video quality fits your needs. A good average is about 2,000 kbps - 4,000 kbps. However, that highly depends on your video's content.